# PHP get_defined_vars, what does the manual means by multidimensional array?

Tags: php

Regarding the PHP function "get_defined_vars" the manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php
says:

> This function returns a **multidimensional** array containing a list of
> all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined
> variables, within the scope that get_defined_vars() is called.

To my understanding "multidimensional array" means an array with more dimensions.
I suppose the description is at least poor or measleading, as in the case of calling get_defined_vars from within a function an associative array is returned having the names of the variables as keys and their values as values.
Does it happens something different in other contexts ?
Is the "multidimensional" totally wrong or there are cases that the results are indeed multidimensional ?

Comment: make your local variable an array and then call get_defined_vars()

Comment: `Does it happens something different in other contexts`... well why not just try it, and then you'll know? e.g. https://3v4l.org/2ahgP - looks like a multidimensional array to me. So yeah it's context-dependent, on whether what's in scope happens to have any arrays in it. The docs could perhaps be a bit better-worded but I wouldn't say it was completely wrong.

Comment: Execute it in the global scope, and you will see that it contains entries for the superglobals `_GET`, `_POST`, `_SERVER` etc. as well. And since those are themselves arrays, you now got a multidimensional array.

Comment: It actually returns list of variables, but technically speaking the list becomes multidimensional when some of your variables are arrays. I think they just meant that the result array is not flat and actually can be very deep. "Does it happens something different in other contexts?" - no. "Is the "multidimensional" totally wrong or there are cases that the results are indeed multidimensional?" - yes, second

Comment: It's not _just_ when it's in a global context, it's _any_ time that any in-scope variable contains an array. Demo 2: https://3v4l.org/vSkJ9

Comment: Indeed in the case that get_defined_vars is called in the global context, than it seems it returns a multidimensional array, but in reality it returns just a simple associative array with keys _GET;_POST;_COOKIE;_FILES;argv;argc;_SERVER;_REQUEST;_ENV;GLOBALS; plus the keys of any global variables it happen to be defined by the user at that time. So I suppose that it would be clearer if stated what exactly returns in each case and I see only two cases global context and function context (is that correct ? ).

Comment: `in reality it returns just a simple associative array`...no, because at least some of those will contain populated data, generally - see my first demo, where SERVER is populated with an array containing various items. A multidimensional array, in PHP at least, is implemented as an array which contains other arrays.

Comment: `I see only two cases global context and function context`...no, those are not distinguishable cases, as my last demo shows.

Comment: Quite simply: It'll return a multidimensional array if at least one in-scope variable is itself an array (because its keys will become subdimensions of the outer array returned by the function).

Comment: I see 2 contexts:the function get_defined_vars called from within a function and then the associative array contains as keys the argument variables plus the local variables defined up to the point the function is called, and as their values contains whatever happens being contained in them. The other context is the function is called in global scope and then the associative array contains as keys all global variables defined by the user plus the super globals and as values the values of those variables whatever they may be. I see no other context. The value being an array is irrelevant.

Comment: No, the value being an array is precisely what controls whether the result is multidimensional or not. I've proved that with my demo - did you look? Here's a 3rd version, for comparison: https://3v4l.org/WJbee . Note that this time the result isn't multi-dimensional because none of the variables in scope when the get_defined_vars function was called are arrays. The global context is a special case only because it reports variables that PHP declared, not just ones which you declared. But if all those PHP variables didn't happen to be arrays, then you still wouldn't get a multidimensional result

Comment: I agree it's misleading: https://github.com/php/doc-en/issues/1317

Comment: I looked at the demos. Thus the description in the manual is wrong and measleading. In the local context if all variables are not arrays it does not return anything multidimensional as you pointed out. Thus the definition is wrong ! The correct one would be: "in global or local context returns an associative array with keys the names respectively of the global or local variables and as values of the array the values of those variables. In the global context also superglobals are returned".If the value of any variable happens to be an array is irrelevant to the description.Suppose we may agree?

Comment: It's slightly misleading in that it doesn't _always_ return a multidimensional array I agree - I mentioned that in my first comment. We agree on that. We only disagreed on what it is that triggers it to return something multidimensional. Your statement is ok but you don't need to put in the `global or local` bit really, as there's no functional difference between what it does in those two context, it's only that it returns a different dataset in each context depending on the scope (which the documentation already states).

Comment: You could consider adding your thoughts to that GitHub issue page

Comment: "If the value of any variable happens to be an array is irrelevant to the description" - yeah, this would be much more adequate and clear than "returns multidimensional array"